# MySQL - id "reservation" before insert

Tags: php, mysql, upload, locking

I need to know the id (and reserve it) for a record that I will insert in database before insert it because I add a product and upload also a image for this product, and the location of image is related to the product id.

I can find the id that will follow, but I need also to keep it "lock" until the product image is uploaded, to be sure that this id isn't used by another user meanwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split this into two operations.

In the first you create everything for the product and get the id.  In the second you update the row with the image you've uploaded, which can now be saved since you know the ID.

Comment: And to be safe, do it inside a transaction, so you can rollback the initial insert in case something goes wrong with the image handling part of the process.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as a transaction

I googled "php mysql transaction" and there are a lot of tutorials on how to do this

http://www.linuxdig.com/news_page/1079394922.php

Answer (score 0):

id reservation can only be done safely if you have your own auto increment implementation. Even when running in a transaction, you can not know for sure what the next id is. You just can be sure what you have when you requested for it.

Some people use the [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to receive the last inserted id. But I have somewhere in mind this function is not threadsafe and you'll probably get the id of another thread which just inserted.

However, in your case only two options come to my mind:

1) create your [own sequence generator](http://devzone.zend.com/article/12566)
2) insert your datarow, select it again with all values in the where clause, and use that id. Run option 2 in a transaction (as already suggested above)

I would go for option 1. Sequence generation is commonly used with all other databases (from the widely used only mysql supports auto increment as far as I know). Sequences therefore are fully acceptable.

Cheers, Christian

Comment: Actually I think mysql_insert_id - Get the ID generated in the last query, and is generated per-connection. "The last ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means the value the function returns to a given client is the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value generated by that client. The value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that you can retrieve your own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions."